# winform listbox drawitem change substring color

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, ondrawitem

I created a winform custom control which has a textbox and listbox both sharing same bindingsource, so that the listbox can be filtered with the textbox input.

I need to override the lisbox drawitem so that the filtered items having searched text as substring to be of different color or highlighted. (i.e.,)Expected the yellow highlight like below sample image.
[image: sample reference]

I did as below

```
private void DrawItemHandler(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                e.DrawBackground();
                e.DrawFocusRectangle();

                string MyString = listBox.GetItemText(listBox.Items[e.Index]);
                string stringToFind = searchInput.Text ;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringToFind))
                {
                    List<int> positions = new List<int>();
                    int pos = 0;
                    while ((pos < MyString.Length) && (pos = MyString.IndexOf(stringToFind, pos, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) != -1)
                    {
                        positions.Add(pos);
                        pos += stringToFind.Length;
                    }

                    int c = 0, nLen = 0, width = 0;
                    Rectangle rect = e.Bounds;
                    rect.X = width;
                    do
                    {
                        if (positions.Contains(c))
                        {
                            //int opacity = 128;
                            e.Graphics.DrawString(MyString.Substring(c, stringToFind.Length),
                                                    e.Font,
                                //new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(opacity, Color.LightYellow)),
                                                    new SolidBrush(Color.LightYellow),
                                                    rect);
                            nLen = MyString.Substring(c, stringToFind.Length).Length;
                            width += nLen;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            e.Graphics.DrawString(MyString[c].ToString(),
                            e.Font,
                            new SolidBrush(listBox.ForeColor),
                            rect);
                            nLen = MyString[c].ToString().Length;
                            width += nLen;
                        }
                        rect.X = width;
                    }
                    while ((c += nLen) < MyString.Length);
                }
                else
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(MyString,
                        e.Font,
                        new SolidBrush(listBox.ForeColor),
                        e.Bounds);
                }

            });

        }
```

and the result was the item text being overwritten characters.

[image: initially]
[image: after search]

I cannot identify the error part, is it in the rectangle bounds or the drawstring part. Also apart from item background color, how can I change the background of substring in the item text. Please help me on this.

Comment: To change the backgroud of the substring, i suspect you must first use FillRectangle and then DrawString over that rectangle

Comment: To use a custom BackColor use TextRenderer instead of DrawString! Your way to advance the rectangle.X is using the length of the string in characters instead of in  pixels.  Use Graphics.MeasureString(...Typographics) to find out how wide the highlighted part is.

Comment: Tried the MeasureString with FillRectangle suggestion and I can see the difference but still need few tweaking. Thanks guys.

Comment: Note that there will always be a little slack. Using the TextRenderer overload with two colors for drawing the string will at least get the BackColor precisely over or rather under  the text.

Comment: Thanks @TaW, I going with textrenderer and will remember this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the task is not as easy as it should be because neither `TextRenderer.MeasureText` nor `Graphics.MeasureString` seems to be very accurate for the job. But using a different overload of `Graphics.MeasureString` passing the rectangle Width and `StringFormat.GenericTypographic` it seems to work a little better.

This is my attempt on your problem, hope it helps:

```
    private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox listBox = (ListBox)sender;
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            e.DrawBackground();
            e.DrawFocusRectangle();

            string MyString = listBox.GetItemText(listBox.Items[e.Index]);
            string stringToFind = searchInput.Text;


            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringToFind))
            {
                string[] strings = MyString.Split(new string[] { stringToFind }, StringSplitOptions.None);

                Rectangle rect = e.Bounds;

                for (int i=0;i<strings.Length;i++)
                {
                    string s = strings[i];
                    if (s != "")
                    {
                        int width = (int)e.Graphics.MeasureString(s, e.Font,e.Bounds.Width, StringFormat.GenericTypographic).Width;
                        rect.Width = width;
                        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, s, e.Font, new Point(rect.X, rect.Y), listBox.ForeColor);
                        rect.X += width;
                    }

                    if (i < strings.Length - 1)
                    {
                        int width2 = (int)e.Graphics.MeasureString(stringToFind, e.Font, e.Bounds.Width, StringFormat.GenericTypographic).Width;
                        rect.Width = width2;
                        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, stringToFind, e.Font, new Point(rect.X, rect.Y), listBox.ForeColor, Color.Yellow);
                        rect.X += width2;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, MyString, e.Font, new Point(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y), listBox.ForeColor);
            }

        });


    }
```

Comment: Finally!!! I tried all the way around with DrawString but got white space in between characters not in the search pattern. Your solution is spot on.